# Apache can't find folder, although it exists

Tags: apache, tensorflow

When running server in development everything works fine.
Once I run the same code in Apache server it gives an error

**NotFoundError at
/Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config; No such file or directory**.

The exact point at which error emerges, seems to be here:

`configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])`

I gave all possible permissions I could only give.

I am using django restframework as backend. But I don't think that's where the problem is.

If anyone have any ideas how to resolve this. I would be super grateful!

Comment: is that space in the beginning of the path part of your configuration?

Comment: @OlafKock Doesn't seem to be

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I figured it out. The problem was that apache needs to have an absolute path. So, if you are building your django project in development put absolute path everywhere.

In my case it looks something like this

`configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file('/var/www/html/BackendUser/'+files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])`